# Use awk to compare the differences between two files when a column matches

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk, grep

I have two txt files that I want to compare. I want to calculate the BudgetSpent between the two files if and only if the first column (FirstName) and second column (LastName) in the first txt file matches the second file's first and second column.

So basically if `file1.txt`'s `Firstname` == `file2.txt`'s `Firstname` && `file1.txt`'s `LastName`== `file2.txt`'s `LastName`, I want it to generate a third file whereby it generates all the columns that matched, and one extra column which would be the `BudgetSpentDifferences`.

*`file1.txt`*

```
FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpent
Taylor Swift 23 1000
Joe Smith 30 5000
```

*`file2.txt`*

```
FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpent
Joe Smith 30 5200
Taylor Swift 23 800
Joe Johnson 22 100
```

This is how I want the third file generated to be:
*`file3.txt`*

```
FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpentDifferences
Taylor Swift 23 200
Joe Smith 30 -200
```

I am really confused as I am quite new to `awk`. Please help me out :( I've been scrambling my head thinking about how to generate this. Not sure if there's an if condition that can input two files in `awk`.

Thanks,

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR && NR>1 { a[$1 " " $2] = $4; next}
NR!=FNR && FNR==1 { $4 = "BudgetSpent"; print }
NR!=FNR && FNR>1 && ($1 " " $2) in a { $4 -=  a[$1 " " $2]; print}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

prints

```
FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpent
Joe Smith 30 200
Taylor Swift 23 -200
```

Explanation:

- `NR == FNR` is true for the first file
- `NR > 1` is true for the second and later lines total
- `FNR == 1` is true for the first line of every file
- `a[$1 " " $2] = $4` creates an entry in an associative array `a` with the combination `FirstName LastName` (separated by a single space) as key and `BudgetSpent` as value
- `($1 " " $2) in a` is true if the combination `FirstName LastName` is a valid key in `a`
- `$4 -=  a[$1 " " $2]` subtracts the value retrieved from `a` with key `FirstName LastName` from the value of field 4 (`BudgetSpent`)

**Note** that the script will not work if `FirstName` or `LastName` contains spaces. Apart from using some other character (e.g. TAB) as field separator, the array key might be ambiguous in this case.

---

There are nearly always different / simpler / shorter ways to solve a problem.

Citing jhnc's comment:

> `NR>1` and `NR!=FNR` conditions are unnecessary.

If the condition `NR>1` is omitted, the array `a` will also contain an entry based on the heading which should not be a problem. As the first condition then covers all lines of the first file and the action contains `next`, the second and third line of the script will be executed only for the second file (and later), so the condition `NR!=FNR` can be removed.

> You can reduce typing by assigning composite key to a variable: `{u=$1" "$2} NR==FNR{a[u]=$4;next} u in a{ $4 = FNR==1?"Diff":$4-a[u]; print }`

Comment: If names can contain spaces, then you would need to set FS.

Comment: `NR>1` and `NR!=FNR` conditions are unnecessary. You can reduce typing by assigning composite key to a variable: `{u=$1" "$2} NR==FNR{a[u]=$4;next} u in a{ $4 = FNR==1?"Diff":$4-a[u]; print }`

Answer (score 1):

For GNU awk use a multi-demensional array for the name index:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0"Differences"; next}
     NR==FNR{a[$1][$2]=$4; next}
     $1 in a && $2 in a[$1]{$4-=a[$1][$2]; print}' file1 file2
```

For POSIX awk, use spaces to index "FirstName LastName":

```
awk 'NR==1{print $0"Differences";next}
     NR==FNR{a[$1" "$2]=$4;next}
     $1" "$2 in a{$4-=a[$1 " " $2]; print}' file1 file2
```

For POSIX awk: If input names may contain spaces (but no tabs), use `-F'\t'` to set input field separator to tab and change `" "` to `"\t"`:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{print $0"Differences";next}
   NR==FNR{a[$1"\t"$2]=$4;next}
   $1"\t"$2 in a{$4-=a[$1"\t"$2]; print}' file1 file2
```

Result:

```
FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpentDifferences
Joe Smith 30 200
Taylor Swift 23 -200
```

- Line 1: Print "FirstName LastName Age BudgetSpentDifferences".
- Line 2: Create a two-dimensional index in the form `array[FirstName][LastName]=BudgetSpent` from file1.
- Line 3: In case of an index match in file2, subtract the Budgets and print the results.

Comment: posix awk doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. I believe `a[$1,$2]` would be more normal

Comment: @jhnc mh, and then `sprintf("%s%c%s", $1, 28, $2) in a`?

Comment: in this context `,` is `SUBSEP` (which defaults to `RS`), so `u = $1 SUBSEP $2 ... u in a ...` or `$1 RS $2 in a`

Comment: @jhnc : what do you mean `SUBSEP` defaulting to `RS` ?

Answer (score 0):

to build upon @`steffen`'s, solution, here's one for all `awk`s :

```
awk 'BEGIN { ____ = (_+= __ = _^= SUBSEP = FS )^_ 
     } __ == NR && sub("$", "Differences")  ||
      FNR == NR ? (___[$__, $_] = $____)<"" : \
     ($__, $_) in ___ && ($____ -= ___[$__, $_])^!_' f1 f2
```